# Why is my Python Plotly bar chart not stacking the traces correctly?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

OK I have gone round and round with this and rewritten it several times. Maybe you guys know whats going on here?

I have this python code:

```
branches = ['AMN', 'ACF']
    cy = ["$33,532.80","$29,798.24"]
    ly = ["$35,612.46", "$15,966.40"]

    trace1 = go.Bar(
    x = branches,
    y = cy,
    text=cy,
    textposition='auto',
    name = "2023-05-25"
    )

    trace2 = go.Bar(
    x = branches,
    y = ly,
    text=ly,
    textposition='auto',
    name = "2022-05-25")
    )
    
    data = [trace1, trace2]
    layout = go.Layout(barmode = 'stack')
    fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
```

The output is:
[Image of code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAwDc.png)

See how the value from the 2023 trace is the base and not shown?  it clearly has the data just not showing right... any help here would be appreciated :-)

I have rewritten it in PX and plain plotly and have changed the syntax a round several times, searched through the docs and I can not make sense of whats happening here.

should be a stacked set of traces with current year and last year numbers on it.

Comment: First of all, the y-axis value you think is a number is a string. So you can draw the intended graph by removing the currency indication and the rank. You can also add the following code for the y-axis notation. `cy = [33532.80,29798.24];ly = [35612.46, 15966.40]` and `fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat = '$')`

Comment: This was exactly it! thank you.  works properly now and I understand what I did wrong here.